# Error: Invalid numeric value (NaN, or not-a-number) to CoreGraphics API - possibly related to UITextview in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, uitextview

When I hover over text sections in my swiftUI app, which uses UITextView representable, I receive this strange warning in the simulator. On actual devices, this cannot be duplicated.

```
Error: this application, or a library it uses, has passed an invalid numeric value (NaN, or not-a-number) to CoreGraphics API and this value is being ignored. Please fix this problem.

If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_NUMERICS_SHOW_BACKTRACE
```

When enabling  CG_NUMERICS_SHOW_BACKTRACE I get this back trace.

```
2023-06-04 10:21:38.983039+0100 TextViewRepresentable[12699:10411840] [Unknown process name] Error: this application, or a library it uses, has passed an invalid numeric value (NaN, or not-a-number) to CoreGraphics API and this value is being ignored. Please fix this problem.
2023-06-04 10:21:38.992493+0100 TextViewRepresentable[12699:10411840] [Unknown process name] Backtrace:
  <CGPathMoveToPoint+71>
   <+[UIBezierPath _continuousRoundedRectBezierPath:withRoundedCorners:cornerRadii:segments:smoothPillShapes:]+1636>
    <+[UIBezierPath _continuousRoundedRectBezierPath:withRoundedCorners:cornerRadius:segments:]+170>
     <+[UIBezierPath _roundedRectBezierPath:withRoundedCorners:cornerRadius:segments:legacyCorners:]+337>
      <-[UIScrollViewAccessibility accessibilityPath]+1575>
       <-[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) _accessibilityBaseHitTest:withEvent:]+2879>
        <-[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) _accessibilityHitTest:withEvent:]+92>
         <-[UIViewAccessibility _accessibilityHitTest:withEvent:]+154>
          <-[UIViewAccessibility __accessibilityHitTest:withEvent:]+1675>
           <-[UIViewAccessibility _accessibilityHitTest:withEvent:]+101>
            <__64-[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) _accessibilityBaseHitTest:withEvent:]_block_invoke.243+180>
             <-[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) _accessibilityBaseHitTest:withEvent:]+4038>
              <-[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) _accessibilityHitTest:withEvent:]+92>
               <-[UIViewAccessibility _accessibilityHitTest:withEvent:]+154>
                <-[UIViewAccessibility __accessibilityHitTest:withEvent:]+1675>
                 <-[UIViewAccessibility _accessibilityHitTest:withEvent:]+101>
                  <-[UIViewAccessibility __accessibilityHitTest:withEvent:]+1675>
                   <-[UIViewAccessibility _accessibilityHitTest:withEvent:]+101>
                    <-[UIViewAccessibility __accessibilityHitTest:withEvent:]+1675>
                     <-[UIViewAccessibility _accessibilityHitTest:withEvent:]+101>
                      <-[UIWindowAccessibility _accessibilityHitTest:withEvent:]+138>
                       <_copyElementAtPositionCallback+5184>
                        <___AXXMIGCopyElementAtPosition_block_invoke+79>
                         <_handleNonMainThreadCallback+424>
                          <_AXXMIGCopyElementAtPosition+670>
                           <_XCopyElementAtPosition+521>
                            <mshMIGPerform+1024>
                             <__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__+41>
                              <__CFRunLoopDoSource1+538>
                               <__CFRunLoopRun+2671>
                                <CFRunLoopRunSpecific+560>
                                 <GSEventRunModal+139>
                                  <-[UIApplication _run]+994>
                                   <UIApplicationMain+123>
                                    <__swift_memcpy93_8+12403>
                                     <__swift_memcpy93_8+12076>
                                      <__swift_memcpy195_8+14237>
                                       <$s21TextViewRepresentable0abC3AppV5$mainyyFZ+30>
                                        <main+9>
                                         107c8d384
```

Any ideas how significant this is, as it only happens on the simulator, and how to resolve it?
Thanks

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing the code On the top of the backtrace there is a call to `UIBezierPath`, one of the parameters passed to that would be the first suspect. You mention UITextView, I have to guess, but are you parsing the input and getting a number from the input? Perhaps that conversion didn't go as expected but hard to say without seeing the code.

Comment: I have a similar error, but with `updateAutocorrectPrompt` in the stack trace instead of your accessibility related calls. It happens every time I type a letter in a particular UITextField, and only if I use the Mac keyboard. I am assuming it is a bug in the simulator. It doesn't impact any functionality as far as I can see.

Comment: I have the same error and I use a UITextField. I have stripped my Xcode project to nothing, just a ViewController with a UITextField, not even implementing any delegation function. Just the UITextField. And I get the same error.

Comment: Does this just happen in the simulator or on real device? An Apple engineer told me that I can ignore it.